# Confuse about testing-library container query methods

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

when i use testing-library, i'd like to use container api to find element, like

```
"container.querySelector('button')"
```

It's easy to use for me, but the official document says:

> If you find yourself using container to query for rendered elements then you should reconsider! The other queries are designed to be more resilient to changes that will be made to the component you're testing. Avoid using container to query for elements!

So my question is what is the real difference between container.querySelector and getByXX/queryByXX? In performance?

I'd like to use container.querySelector, and i found many library also use it, so how are their application scenarios different?

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of performance. It's more about abstraction. Using the container API means you have to know about the HTML structure rendered by your component (generally you try to avoid this in React), where using the getByXX/queryByXX is a bit more abstract. That being said the container API can be the only way or most convenient way to grab an element.

Comment: From the [guiding principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/): 

"The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you. / We try to only expose methods and utilities that encourage you to write tests that closely resemble how your web pages are used."

Comment: Another post that provides details on the subject: 

"we want to avoid selecting elements by classNames, ids, or even test ids, because that is not how the user would find the element on the screen.

querySelector as a query strategy is vulnerable to DOM changes or if we are basing the selectors on CSS Styling, the CSS Styling locators can change independently of the functionality and we may find functional-based tests failing due to styling changes." ~ https://medium.com/smallcase-engineering/why-should-we-not-use-document-queryselector-while-testing-react-components-835bbf34169e#7aa1